# Stack implementation java - LinkedList vs Vector

Tags: java, stack

I wanted to know why Stack is implemented using Vector and not with LinkedList. As far as I know, LinkedList provides more efficient structure for deletion and insertion of elements. So, why stack is implemented using vector and not LinkedList. Java implements Queue interface with LinkedList and since in both stack and queue, insertion and deletion is the primary function, why not linkedlist for Stack.

Comment: `java.util.Stack` is a very early class that predates the Java collections framework. If a `Stack` type were being added today, you could expect it to be an interface implemented by lots of classes including `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stack` and `Vector` are both old classes.

If you read the Javadoc of `Stack`, you'll see that it suggests using `Deque` instead:

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.

And `LinkedList` does implement the `Deque` interface.

Answer (score 5):

> As far as I know, `LinkedList` provides more efficient structure for deletion and insertion of elements.

That is not actually true ... in the context of stack operations.  (Or in general).

A `Vector` is a form of array list.  It works by allocating an array to hold a number of elements, and using array indexing to access and update the list.  Insertion and deletion at a random position in the `Vector` is expensive because it entails copying multiple element references.

However, that not what a `Stack` requires.  It actually requires insertion and deletion *exclusively* at the end of the `Vector`, and that is cheap.  In most cases, insertion and deletion simply involves assigning an element into an array cell and adjusting the `Vector` object's `length` field.  It only gets expensive if there is not enough space in the array.  Then the array has to be "grown" by creating a new one and copying the elements.  But when an array list grows the array exponentially (e.g. by doubling its size), the math says that the *amortized*  cost is `O(1)` over the lifetime of the array list.

By contrast, *every time* you insert an element into a `LinkedList`, it involves allocating a new internal "node" object to hold the element.  That is more expensive on average than a `Vector` insertion, especially when you take into account the GC costs incurred over the lifetime of the "node" object.

It also turns out a `LinkedList` uses up to 4 times as much memory per element as a `Vector` does, assuming we are using 64 bit references.

In short, a `Vector` is more efficient and uses less space than a `LinkedList` for a stack data structure.  The correct design choice was made<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - As you would expect.  We can assume that the engineers who designed and maintained Java over the last ~25 years knew what they were doing.  Or that the tens of thousands of other people who have looked at that code since it was written would also have noticed a (hypothetical!) mistake of that magnitude and logged a bug report.</sup>